# How to make a dynamic generated layout responsive for different screen size and devices

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-custom-view, screen-size

The custom view and its content are not responsive to different screen sizes. for example background image and the small circle inside the game. In general how to make every thing in canvas responsive ? 
As you see in the picture the size of green circle is match with the size of screen.

[Same circle in different screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueKFq.png)

```
private int yellowX, yellowY;
private Paint yellowPaint = new Paint();


private Bitmap backgroundImage;


public flyingFishView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);

    yellowPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    yellowPaint.setAntiAlias(false);


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int canvasWidth = getWidth();
    int canvasHeight = getHeight();

    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage,0, 0,null);
}
```

And this is `mainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private flyingFishView gameview;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static long Interval = 40;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameview = new flyingFishView(this);
        setContentView(gameview);

       Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        gameview.invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, Interval );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Without that, your  question is a bit too broad and we won't be able to help.

Comment: And is this for `Android`? You did not include that tag in your question so I will add it for you.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "responsive"? You know about mouse or action listeners, that can react to user input?

Comment: I want every component inside the canvas show up the same scale in different screen sizes. The background image is zoomed in small device and not shown properly and in devices with big screen it shown very small.